Proper height of \dagger on ket?
I'm writing a text with lots of braket notation and daggers attached to them. I noticed that depending on how I write the ket, the ^\dagger appears at different heights and now I'm obsessing about the "correct" height. Either construct seems to make no difference in line spacing when in the middle of a paragraph. Is there a "right" way, eg., AMS-preferred style?
Example:

Latex:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{braket}
\begin{document}
\noindent
With \verb|\ket{a}^\dagger|: $\ket{a}^\dagger$, $|a\rangle^\dagger$ with \verb@ |a\rangle^\dagger@.

\def\lore{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet}
\def\ll{\lore\lore}
\ll\ll\ll\ll $\ket{a}^\dagger$ \ll\ll\ll\ll \par
\ll\ll\ll\ll $|a\rangle^\dagger$ \ll\ll\ll\ll
\end{document}


The difference is basically |a\rangle^\dag vs. {|a\rangle}^\dag (alright, braket does something else too but that's not relevant). As far as the height of the dagger I'd say it's a matter of taste. But as far as writing a manuscript goes, I would never use |a\rangle. Use a syntactic command like \ket, whether from braket or with \DeclarePairedDelimiter from mathtools.

Using \smash works too:
\def\ket#1{\mathinner{\smash{|{#1}\rangle}}}

$\ket{a}^\dagger$, $|a\rangle^\dagger$

\bye

If we want (for some reason) to use the same concept like shown in the answer with me{_^} in OpTeX then we can use \isnextchar macro and simply implement \afterlimits macro:
\def\ket#1{\mathinner\bgroup |{#1}\rangle \afterlimits\egroup}
\def\afterlimits#1{\isnextchar _{\afterlimitsA{#1}}
                  {\isnextchar ^{\afterlimitsA{#1}}{#1}}}
\def\afterlimitsA#1#2#3{#2{#3}\afterlimits{#1}}

\verbchar`

With `\ket{a}^\dagger`: $\ket{a}^\dagger$, 
$|a\rangle^\dagger$ with `|a\rangle^\dagger`.

With `\ket{a}_2`: $\ket{a}_2$, 
$|a\rangle_2$ with `|a\rangle_2`.

\bye

We can try $\tracingmacros=2 \ket{a}^\dagger$. We get 84 tracing lines with OpTeX. On the other hand, if we try the same with the LuaLaTeX solution presented here, we get 1800 tracing lines. I don't understand what LuaLaTeX is doing here. Its tracing information is almost unreadable.

This is the relevant code from braket.sty:
\def\ket#1{\mathinner{|{#1}\rangle}}

Thus \ket{a}^\dagger becomes
\mathinner{|{a}\rangle}^\dagger

and the superscript is to the entire subformula, not just to \rangle.
We can fix the issue by a token lookup provided by \NewDocumentCommand with its embellishment argument type. Look for “embellishment“ in texdoc usrguide for more information.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{braket}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\ket}{me{_^}}{%
  \mathinner{%
    |{#1}\rangle
    \IfValueT{#2}{_{#2}}
    \IfValueT{#3}{^{#3}}
  }%
}

\begin{document}

With \verb|\ket{a}^\dagger|: $\ket{a}^\dagger$, 
$|a\rangle^\dagger$ with \verb@|a\rangle^\dagger@.

With \verb|\ket{a}_2|: $\ket{a}_2$, 
$|a\rangle_2$ with \verb@|a\rangle_2@.

\end{document}



What is the benefit of enclosing it in \mathinner at all?

@Gaussler Spacing around the ket.
